# Python Neural Networking: Run 10 iterations but I get the same output

Tags: python, input, iteration, neural-network, activation

I'm new to coding so I'm having some simple issues. When I run 10 iterations, I get the same numbers.. -0.5 for activation and 0.0 for input even though at the bottom I set the starting activation's to 1.0, 1.0 and 0.0 to each corresponding node in the nodes list.

I thought by setting initial states. They send an input to the other node: which is the sender.activation * weight of 1. I SHOULDVE gotten a new input value. Which then would be applied to my activation which I then would be able to -0.5 and get a new activation for the node.

At least that's what I TRIED to do. And somehow it's just spitting out 0.0 and -0.5.

```
# 
#                               Preparations 
# 

nodes=[] 
NUMNODES=3

# 
#                                   Defining Node Class
# 

class Node(object): 

    def __init__(self,name=None): 
        self.name=name 
        self.activation_threshold=1.0
        self.net_input=0.0
        self.outgoing_connections=[] 
        self.incoming_connections=[] 
        self.connections=[] 
        self.activation=None

    def addconnection(self,sender,weight=0.0):
        self.connections.append(Connection(self,sender,weight)) 

    def update_input(self): 
        self.net_input=0.0
        for conn in self.connections: 
            self.net_input += conn.weight * conn.sender.activation 
        print 'Updated Input is', self.net_input 

    def update_activation(self): 
        self.activation = self.net_input - 0.5
        print 'Updated Activation is', self.activation 

# 
#                                   Defining Connection Class
# 

class Connection(object): 
    def __init__(self, sender, reciever, weight=1.0): 
        self.weight=weight 
        self.sender=sender 
        self.reciever=reciever 
        sender.outgoing_connections.append(self) 
        reciever.incoming_connections.append(self) 
# 
#                                 Other Programs 
# 


def set_activations(act_vector): 
    """Activation vector must be same length as nodes list"""
    for i in xrange(len(act_vector)): 
        nodes[i].activation = act_vector[i] 


for i in xrange(NUMNODES): 
    nodes.append(Node()) 


for i in xrange(NUMNODES):#go thru all the nodes calling them i 
    for j in xrange(NUMNODES):#go thru all the nodes calling them j 
        if i!=j:#as long as i and j are not the same 
            nodes[i].addconnection(nodes[j])#connects the nodes together
#
#                                         Setting Activations
#
set_activations([1.0,1.0,0.0])

#
#                                        Running 10 Iterations
#

for i in xrange(10): 
    for thing in nodes: 
        thing.update_activation() 
        thing.update_input()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you coded that

```
def addconnection(self,sender,weight=0.0):
    self.connections.append(Connection(self,sender,weight)) 
    print "Node", str(self), "now contains", str(self.connections[-1])
```

and you call it with

```
nodes[i].addconnection(nodes[j]) #connects the nodes together
```

You don't specify a weight right here. So you might be thinking that you're using the default value `weight = 1.0` of the Connections class, but you're not.
If you look closely, you do specify `weight = 0.0` as default parameter in defining `addconnection`, right? :
`def addconnection(self,sender,weight=0.0):`

And since you call the Connection class `__init__` method with
`self.connections.append(Connection(self,sender,weight))`
you actually pass it a value for weight: the default `0.0` you specified in the addconnection method. So all the connections will have the default weight `0.0`. This effectively locks all values for inputs at 0.0 and activations at -0.5.

To change this, you could perhaps specify a weight at line 75 where you use the `addconnection` method, and/or let only `addconnection` have a default value for weight (and let it be 1.0) while the Connection class `__init__` method should always require a `weight` value, with no default. This is what I did in the code below, plus some `__str__` methods to check things up.

(This is a version with a default value of `1.0` in `addconnection` and no default in the Connection `__init__`):

[EDIT: Added a first initialization of `net_input`.]

```
# 
#                               Preparations 
# 

nodes=[] 
NUMNODES=3

# 
#                                   Defining Node Class
# 

class Node(object): 

    def __init__(self,name=None): 
        self.name=name 
        self.activation_threshold=1.0
        self.net_input=0.0
        self.outgoing_connections=[] 
        self.incoming_connections=[] 
        self.connections=[] 
        self.activation=None

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def addconnection(self,sender,weight=1.0):
        self.connections.append(Connection(self,sender,weight)) 
        print "Node", str(self), "now contains", str(self.connections[-1])

    def update_input(self): 
        self.net_input=0.0
        for conn in self.connections: 
            self.net_input += conn.weight * conn.sender.activation 
        print 'Updated Input for node', str(self), 'is', self.net_input 

    def update_activation(self): 
        self.activation = self.net_input - 0.5
        print 'Updated Activation for node', str(self), 'is', self.activation 

# 
#                                   Defining Connection Class
# 

class Connection(object): 
    def __init__(self, sender, reciever, weight): 
        self.weight=weight 
        self.sender=sender 
        self.reciever=reciever 
        sender.outgoing_connections.append(self) 
        reciever.incoming_connections.append(self) 
        print 'Created', str(self)

    def __str__(self):
        string = "Connection from " + str(self.sender) + " to " + str(self.reciever) + ", weight = " + str(self.weight)
        return string
# 
#                                 Other Programs 
# 


def set_activations(act_vector): 
    """Activation vector must be same length as nodes list"""
    for i in xrange(len(act_vector)): 
        nodes[i].activation = act_vector[i] 


for i in xrange(NUMNODES): 
    nodes.append(Node(str(i)))
    print "Created node:", nodes[i]


for i in xrange(NUMNODES):#go thru all the nodes calling them i 
    for j in xrange(NUMNODES):#go thru all the nodes calling them j 
        if i!=j:#as long as i and j are not the same 
            nodes[i].addconnection(nodes[j])#connects the nodes together
#
#                                         Setting Activations
#
set_activations([1.0,1.0,0.0])

#
#                                        Running 10 Iterations
#
for thing in nodes:
    thing.update_input() #initializing inputs

for i in xrange(10): 
    for thing in nodes: 
        thing.update_activation() 
        thing.update_input()
```

Comment: Oh thanks I see what I did wrong now. I thought it would overwrite it the other way. Hmm but the values I'm getting are all the same even though I set the activation to 1.0, 1.0, and 0.0. I don't know why all 3 values are the same.

Comment: Oh - it's because you call `update_activation` right away, when `self.net_input` has the default value of 0.0 for every node (you didn't initialize it yet), so all activations are set to -0.5.
You should initialize `net_input` first (with `update_input` I suppose?), and only then call `update_activation`.

Comment: I added an initialization of `net_input` to the script, see if this is the expected behavior!

Comment: Ah! This makes so much sense and it's so much cleaner. Letting me know which Node is doing what update. Wow I love u right now haha. Does "str" make it a number?

Comment: I used `nodes.append(Node(str(i)))` to make `i` into a string and use it as the `name` argument that you specified in the Node `__init__` method :) From that point on, each node has its `self.name`, and this name is contained in the return of the `__str__` method :)